# Between trusted domain SharePoint is asking for credential for open with explorer

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-foundation, single-sign-on, explorer-view, trusted-domain

I am working on multiple SharePoint environments.

**Details:**
Recently we **migrated all users from** one domain (say **Domain 'A'**) to another domain (say **Domain 'B'**).
Now the users are on new domain (Domain 'B') and SharePoint (both versions 2010 and 2007) is installed on old domain (Domain 'A').
Both the **domains are trusted** (two way trusted).
"Single Sign On" **(SSO) is working** on SharePoint 2010 and MOSS 2007.

**Problem:**
Now user is **getting authentication pop-up** (asking for credentials) **while opening the Explorer View** of a Document Library. The Document Library is in MOSS 2007 site.

**Q:**
Is there any way to avoid this pop-up?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see whether MOSS 2007 is opening in Explorer View using FPRPC vs. WebDAV. If so, force it open with WebDAV.

Also, check out the troubleshooting section of [Understanding and Troubleshooting the SharePoint Explorer View](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C523AC7A-5724-48BE-B973-641E805588F4&displaylang=en).

Comment: Thanks for the response. How to check "Explorer View using FPRPC vs. WebDAV"?

Comment: @MAK There are some visual cues as mentioned on pages 9-10 of the troubleshooting guide (see link in answer). For starters, explorer view using FPRPC will appear different (flatter looking folders, fewer options) than explorer view using WebDAV (3D looking folders, full set of Windows Explorer options).